# Make Int typealiases that aren't assignment compatible

Tags: swift

I would like to make some Integer types that aren't assignment compatible, like the below.

```
    typealias Fatty = Int
    typealias Skinny = Int

    var a : Fatty = 6
    var b: Skinny = 4

    a = b // This should throw a compile time error saying the types are incompatible

    a = Fatty(b) // this should work
```

Is there any way to do this in swift (without making a class/struct)? Used to be able to do this in pascal.

Comment: You must define your own type (class/struct), there're no other way. `typealias` does not define any new type.

Comment: If you define your type as a `struct` containing only one member of a Swift type, you should find that most of the overhead of using a `struct` gets optimised away by the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can define your own integer types but it's not so easy:

```
public struct Fatty: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, Hashable {
    public typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int
    let value: Int

    public init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    public init(_ skinny: Skinny) {
        self.value = skinny.value
    }

    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

public struct Skinny: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, Hashable {
    public typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int
    let value: Int

    public init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    public init(_ fatty: Fatty) {
        self.value = fatty.value
    }

    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

If you want to types to behave like real integers, you can make them conform to `BinaryInteger` (or other integer protocols).

Can be somehow generalized using a protocol:

```
public protocol CustomInt: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, Hashable, Comparable {
    associatedtype ValueType = _ExpressibleByBuiltinIntegerLiteral
    var value: ValueType { get set }

    init(value: ValueType)
}

extension CustomInt {
    public init(integerLiteral value: ValueType) {
        self.init(value: value)
    }

    public init<T: CustomInt>(_ customInt: T) where Self.ValueType == T.ValueType {
        self.init(value: customInt.value)
    }
}

extension CustomInt where ValueType: Comparable {
   public static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
      return lhs.value < rhs.value
   }
}

public struct Fatty: CustomInt {
    public var value: Int

    public init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

public struct Skinny: CustomInt {
    public var value: Int

    public init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but do I still have to implement all the operators? e.g. '<', seems like it, I just tried your code. Seems an awful lot of typing, which was what I was trying to avoid

Comment: @daven11 Added `Comparable`. That should show you how to implement other operations too. The trick with a protocol helps to avoid duplication for every custom type.

Comment: Also note that you don't have to define everything. Swift protocol extensions will define a lot for you once you implement the basic methods to comply to a protocol.

Comment: hmm, how would I find out the basic methods? Forgive my newbiness I haven't done much with protocols - not at this level. Don't suppose this is documented anywhere? I find the Math.Integers a little difficult to read

Comment: @daven11 What other operations do you need?

Comment: Oh only a few - %, += and so on. I'm implementing them now, fairly easy. I was wondering what the basic methods you alluded to are, and how I would find them.